# Switching the columns of two CSVs using PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, csv

I currently have two CSVs with the following data:

This is the first CSV, and it continues like this for about 300 people. There are about 10 other columns that includes info related to payments they have made, but the Ancillary column is the one that needs to be modified.

```
+-------------------------------------+--+
|              Ancillary              |  |
+-------------------------------------+--+
| EXT_TRANS_ID=111111111 - John Smith |  |
| EXT_TRANS_ID=222222222 - Joe Joe    |  |
| EXT_TRANS_ID=333333333 - Ben Ben    |  |
| ...                                 |  |
+-------------------------------------+--+
```

This is the second CSV, and this continues on for about 1000-2000 people. However, the 300 people in the first CSV are within the pool of people within the second CSV.

```
+----------------------------------+----------------+-----------+--+
|           Person Name            | Payment Amount | BannerID  |  |
+----------------------------------+----------------+-----------+--+
| Smith, John                      |            100 | 123456789 |  |
| Roberts, Peter                   |            200 | 342526171 |  |
| Jeff, Smith                      |            400 | 993839383 |  |
| Ben, Ben                         |            600 | 848348983 |  |
| Joe, Joe                         |        1000    | 374834734 |  |
```

My task is to match the people who are in both the first CSV and the second CSV by name, and to replace the content in the Ancillary column of the first CSV with the content of the BannerID column in the second CSV, while leaving all the other columns of the first CSV intact.

For example:

```
+-------------+--+
|  Ancillary  |  |
+-------------+--+
| 123456789   |  |
| 374834734   |  |
| 848348983   |  |
+-------------+--+
```

The codes from the BannerID column of the second CSV are now in Ancillary, but the codes match the original names - if you looked up the first code in Ancillary, for example, you would find John Smith.

I'm not entirely sure how to approach this, especially since the Ancillary column doesn't just contain their names, it contains a code with the name, which seems to make filtering this harder. I also only have experience with basic filtering, and never learned how to match CSVs in this way.

The only code I have is this:

```
csv1['Ancillary'] = csv1['Person BannerID']
```

which successfully inputs the bannerID into the Ancillary column, but because the first CSV has 300 names and the second CSV has 1000 names, the bannerID does not match with the person, which would ruin the data.

This is a task I can do by hand if necessary, but I'd like to automate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching codes in a CSV using PANDAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292763/matching-codes-in-a-csv-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one easy way of doing it.

```
df['Ancillary'] = df['Ancillary'].str.split().str[3] + ', ' + 
df['Ancillary'].str.split().str[2]

df = pd.merge(df, df_2[['Person Name','BannerID']], right_on='Person Name', 
left_on='Ancillary', how='left')

df = df.drop('Ancillary', axis=1)
df = df.drop('Person Name', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for element in zip(csv1['Person Name'], csv1['BannerID']):
    for i, Ancillary in enumerate(csv1['Ancillary']):
       if element[0] in Ancillary:
          csv1['Ancillary'][i] = element[1]
```